# Input password on sudo command

Tags: sudo

Can I input a password on the sudo command itself? Something like:

```
sudo rm (dir) -p (password)
```

I used sudo help but couldn't find a correct syntax (if there is one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The best you can do is to:

- configure sudo such that a user or group of users never need to enter a password for sudo
- configure sudo such that a user or group of users never need to enter a password when running a particular script with sudo.

The latter is recommended practice.  Write a wrapper script that does exactly what needs to be done as root, preferably without taking any user input (e.g. from command-line or env vars), and nothing more.  If you do need to take user input for the script, make sure you properly quote all variables and use other defensive-programming practices.

Answer (score 3):

From [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/233217/1090302), it seems there is a flag `-S` that tells `sudo` to read the password from standard input. The example given there is

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S ls /tmp
```

However it doesn't seem there's any way to give the password as an argument to `sudo` directly.

Also, the security implications of using the password this way must be considered.